# apache server authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, server

I'm completely new to server management, so this is probably a silly question
I followed the instructions given on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache. I also updated the gci.conf file (test example)

Once done, I try to launch my server with service apache2 reload, upon which I'm asked for authentication. I use the sudo password (the only password I have on this machine), enter "gci.example.com" in the address bar and get this response

"This site can’t be reached"

The Apache installation requirements are Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS; I run Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I'm not thrilled about changing OS as I need it only for local website development (forms and the works). I'm also fine with running some other software where I can develop websites using WordPress.

thanks,

Andreas

Comment: That would only work if you have a /etc/hosts entry for gci.example.com to be localhost, which I don't see in the tutorial - unless the Ubuntu apache package sets that up for you by default? But I don't think it should.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit /etc/hosts file, and add:

```
127.0.0.1 gci.example.com
```

But I would suggest you to use localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It turned out that the "sudo service apache2 stop", "sudo service apache2 start" did the trick as well. After this I could use the gci.example.com etc. A reason I can think of is that upon installation the service is started with password. With a reload you need that password (not provided ;-) Thanks again

Comment: @user9165100 did my answer work though? after that. If it helped you, you can upvote.